# How to put restrictions on Pattern of String in Yang Model

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

how can we design the string pattern if i want to allow special characters (#@$%) also to be included in the value for Name.

For Ex.  All the below ones are valid entries for Name

Name = aaa990ZX

Name = a@#9980XS

Name = $$$$$$$$

Name = 00000000

```
typedef Name {
     type string {
         pattern [a-zA-Z0-9];
     }
description
 "Value " ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

YANG uses the [XSD schema regular expression flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) to define such constraints. Simply define and expression such as:

```
pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9#@$%]+';
```

It is recommended to use a single quote string to define a YANG `pattern` statement argument in order to avoid escape sequence problems.

The exact specification of acceptable regular expressions may be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#regexs).

I suggest you read up on regular expressions and perhaps look for a tutorial on it.